# Access related models inside the Loopback isomorphic client

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, isomorphic-javascript

I want to fetch the profiles for a given company using the Loopback isomorphic client.

The Company model makes use of the MySQL connector and the profiles live inside an ElasticSearch instance.

The loopback client is working perfectly inside my front-end app, the following code runs successfully:

```js
let lbclient = window.require('lbclient')

lbclient.models.RemoteProfile.find().done(profiles => {
  // do something with the profiles array
})
```

My goal is to fetch profiles as a nested resource:

> /api/companies/{id}/profiles/

The question is: why the following code doesn't work on the client?

```js
// This is the code I execute on the client
lbclient.models.RemoteCompany.findById(8, (err, company) => {
  company.profiles // undefined
})

// This code works very well on the server
Company.findById(8, (err, company) => {
   company.profiles((err, profiles) => {
     // profiles belong the the company having id=8
   }
})
```

**common/models/company.json**

```js
{
  "name": "Company",
  "plural": "companies",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "My Company"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "profiles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Profile",
      "foreignKey": "company_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**common/models/profile.json**

```js
{
  "name": "Profile",
  "plural": "profiles",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }, 
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "company": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Company",
      "foreignKey": "company_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**client/loopback/models/remote-company.json**

```js
{
  "name": "RemoteCompany",
  "base": "Company",
  "plural": "companies",
  "trackChanges": false,
  "enableRemoteReplication": true
}
```

**client/loopback/models/remote-profile.json**

```js
{
  "name": "RemoteProfile",
  "base": "Profile",
  "plural": "profiles",
  "trackChanges": false,
  "enableRemoteReplication": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include profiles in query like this :

```
lbclient.models.RemoteCompany.findById(8, {include: 'profiles'}, (err, company) => {

})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that was the first solution I came up to, but unfortunately, I cannot perform a "count" that way.

Comment: @AntonioTrapani `count` on what?

Comment: count the profiles owned by the company and subject to a filter. A typical use case is a pagination.

Comment: @AntonioTrapani Aha. You can use [find](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-find) method for pagination and [count](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-count) for counting profiles owned by the company

Comment: sure, I can do that on the server but apparently, there is no way to do that on the client because when I get the company, the object doesn't have the method `company.profiles`.

Comment: @AntonioTrapani Not using `company.profiles`. Just using `count` for counting on model `Profile` and `find` with `include` filter for finding company-profiles on model `Company`

Comment: If I perform the `count` on model `Profile` then I need also to add the authorization logic on the server, overriding the `count` method. This is something I don't want to do because I already structured my application in order to nest all resources under `/companies/{id}` and created a custom, dynamic role for authorization. The point here isn't about designing the application but understanding why accessing related models works very well on the server and not on the client, in something that is called `isomorphic`.